# How to send a big picture in push notification using Apple APN like you do with FCM?

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm new to using Apple APN to send push notifications. With FCM (Firebase), there is an 'image' property you can use to send a big picture with your push notification. It doesn't look like there is an option to send a big picture with your push notification using Apple APN based on this documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification

This is an example of a post request using the Apple APN:

```
   "aps" : {
      "alert" : {
         "title" : "Game Request",
         "subtitle" : "Five Card Draw",
         "body" : "Bob wants to play poker"
      },
      "category" : "GAME_INVITATION"
   },
```

Is there an property you can use in the aps object or the alert object that allows you to send a big picture with your push notification?

How do you send a big picture with your push notification using Apple APN?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending your notifications via firebase?
Then actually there should be an option, but you need then to specify the picture for the different platforms like:

```
const message = {
  notification: {
    title: 'Sparky says hello!'
  },
  android: {
    notification: {
      imageUrl: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'
    }
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        'mutable-content': 1
      }
    },
    fcm_options: {
      image: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'
    }
  },
  webpush: {
    headers: {
      image: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'
    }
  },
  topic: topicName,
};
```

As I understand the documentation and the example here you can only send a link that will be loaded on receiving the picture.
Another idea could be to put the same in a custom payload in a data object within the message. But keep in mind there are some limitations to notifications:

> limits for push payload size determined by Google and Apple — 4096 bytes (in iOS 8 and lower, the maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 2048 bytes [1]).

Links to further explore:
[enter link description here][1]
[enter link description here][2]

[1]: [https://help.pushwoosh.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000440366-Limit-of-characters-that-can-be-sent-through-a-push-notification#:~:text=Answer%3A,is%202048%20bytes%20%5B1%5D](https://help.pushwoosh.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000440366-Limit-of-characters-that-can-be-sent-through-a-push-notification#:%7E:text=Answer%3A,is%202048%20bytes%20%5B1%5D)).
[2]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image

Comment: Thank you. This was useful. I'm hoping to send the push notification using an 'HTTP/2 connection to Apple's servers'. So it's NOT with Firebase. I want to communicate directly with Apple's APN. But I don't see an option to send a big picture with the Apple APN. So I may end up going with Firebase if I can't figure this out.