# Which is the push notification max image size for iOS? (through FCM)

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have found [some limits for the payload like 4kb or 8kb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72382481/how-to-send-a-big-picture-in-push-notification-using-apple-apn-like-you-do-with#:%7E:text=limits%20for%20push%20payload%20size%20determined%20by%20Google,allowed%20for%20a%20notification%20payload%20is%202048%20bytes%29.), but I'm sending images with more than 30kb and it works, so I guess that's not the value for images.

[Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image?hl=pt-br) tells to look for it into Apple docs, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: The image is not embedded in the payload of the message, but is sent as a URL. So only the length of that URL would count towards the payload size limit as far as I know.

Comment: I have sent an image of 900kb, it has arrived on iOS but not on Android. As the 30kb has arrived on both devices, I guessed there was a limit like android (1mb https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-image?hl=pt-br) unfortunately I don't have an iOS device available to test middle sizes...